# python: Fast Fourier Transform data points (0) when the vector being passed through is non zero or NaN

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to set up a different numerical integration for each value of `N`.  All my variables dependent on `N` are returning correctly (I printed the results to make sure everything was coming back fine without NaN or all zeros).  However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid number of FFT data points (0) specified.
```

But the `u` vector has data points.

```
import numpy as np

L = 80.0
dt = 0.0002
tmax = 10
nmax = int(np.floor(tmax / dt))
deltax = []
error = []

for N in [1., 2., 4., 8., 16., 32., 64., 128., 256., 512.]:
    dx = L / N
    deltax.append(dx)
    x = np.arange(-L / 2.0, L / 2.0 - dx, dx)
    k = np.hstack((np.arange(0, N / 2.0 - 1.0),
                   np.arange(-N / 2.0, 0))).T * 2.0 * np.pi / L
    k1 = 1j * k
    k3 = (1j * k) ** 3
    u = 2 * (2 / (np.exp(x + 20.0) + np.exp(-x - 20.0))) ** 2
    udata = u
    tdata = 0.0
    #  integration
    for nn in range(1, nmax + 1):
        du1 = (-np.fft.ifft(k3 * np.fft.fft(u)) -
               3 * np.fft.ifft(k1 * np.fft.fft(u ** 2)))
        v = u + 0.5 * du1 * dt
        du2 = (-np.fft.ifft(k3 * np.fft.fft(v)) -
               3 * np.fft.ifft(k1 * np.fft.fft(v ** 2)))
        v = u + 0.5 * du2 * dt
        du3 = (-np.fft.ifft(k3 * np.fft.fft(v)) -
               3 * np.fft.ifft(k1 * np.fft.fft(v ** 2)))
        v = u + du3 * dt
        du4 = (-np.fft.ifft(k3 * np.fft.fft(v)) -
               3 * np.fft.ifft(k1 * np.fft.fft(v ** 2)))
        u = u + (du1 + 2.0 * du2 + 2.0 * du3 + du4) * dt / 6.0
        error.append(max(abs(u[:,-1] - 2. *
                             (2. / (np.exp(x - 20) + np.exp(-x - 60))))))
        if np.mod(nn, np.ceil(nmax / 20.0)) == 0:
            udata = np.vstack((udata, u))
            tdata = np.vstack((tdata, nn * dt))
```

So all the vectors are being populate but I don't know what the problem is.
If I set `N` to one number and remove that `for` loop, everything works fine but when I add the loop, it all breaks down.
Unfortunately, I can't figure it out.

If you test the code by setting `N = 64` or something, you then have to comment out `deltax` and `error.append`.

Comment: *If I set N to one number and remove that for loop, everything works fine* -- are you sure?  I get the same ValueError if I do that.

Comment: @jedwards you have to comment out deltax and error.append then

Comment: For `N=1.`, `len(x) = 0` which causes `len(u) = 0`.  Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `N = 1` you have `dx = 80.` and `x = numpy.arange(-40, -40, 80)` which gives you an array of size `0`. Consequently, `u` has size `0` too, which `fft` does not like.

Comment: It shouldn't have such a problem at 1 though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. That's how ``arange`` handles ``start == end`` case. If you don't like it, add a condition for ``N = 1`` that sets ``x = [-L/2]`` (or ``0``, or ``L/2``, whichever you think is appropriate).

Comment: I removed 1 but would you know why error.append(max(abs(u[:,-1] - 2. * 52 (2. / (np.exp(x - 20) + np.exp(-x - 60)))))) would have an invalid index?

Comment: I expect it is because ``u`` is one-dimensional, and yet you index it as more-than-two-dimensional in ``u[:,-1]``.

Comment: How do I compare the the time steps of 10 then which should be the last index?

Comment: This conversation is completely off-topic now, and again I do not quite understand what you mean. It seems as if you are trying to compare your numerical simulation with the analytical solution on every step, but it looks weird. I can only generally suggest you think about which shapes your arrays have at every step, and stop indexing them incorrectly.

Comment: I am trying to compare an analytical with a numerical but I want to do it at the t = 10 time step.  If I knew how to index them correctly, I would definitely do that.